# Javascript function fails to update value in html (span id)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to follow a really basic tutorial on javascript, and I know I've had similar code to this work in the past but for some reason the following function fails to update the section in html called `<span id="current-result">`, see below:

**Within app.js:**

```
let currentResult = 1;
currentResult = currentResult + 10;

outputResult(currentResult,'');
alert(currentResult);

const currentResultOutput = document.getElementById('current-result');
const currentCalculationOutput = document.getElementById('current-calculation');

function outputResult(result, text) {
  currentResultOutput.textContent = result;
  currentCalculationOutput.textContent = text;
}
```

**Within index.html:**

```
<body>

<script src="assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>

<section id="results">
  <h2 id="current-calculation">0</h2>
  <h2>Result: <span id="current-result">0</span></h2>
</section>

</body>
```

I also notice that after making changes, saving all the various .js and .html files and refreshing on the browser which is just opening the .html file on local, not everything updates. For example, if I changed the 0 to a 10 directly in the html. I'm doing this in visual studio and using firefox as the browser to open the html file although I checked on chrome as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the element even before the javascript initializes the constants. Look into the concept of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in javascript. Also, the script tag should be at the end or you can use window.onload event handler to initalize your javascript code.

```js
let currentResult = 1;
currentResult = currentResult + 10;

const currentResultOutput = document.getElementById('current-result');
const currentCalculationOutput = document.getElementById('current-calculation');

function outputResult(result, text) {
  currentResultOutput.textContent = result;
  currentCalculationOutput.textContent = text;
}

outputResult(currentResult, '');
alert(currentResult);
```

```html
<section id="results">
  <h2 id="current-calculation">0</h2>
  <h2>Result: <span id="current-result">0</span></h2>
</section>

<script src="assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep, that's the answer. I've done some vba coding but just starting to try web development. Not used to how javascript interacts with html and didn't realize the order in which the <script src="assets/scripts/apps.js"></script> is located was impacting it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Remember to move the function calls to the end as in the answer, also this answer might be confusing to new programmers if they miss the first two sentences, please add an ", Also" or a few newlines since it covers two problems in few sentences

Answer (score 0):

Move your `script` tags below the elements you need to select, since at the time the script is executed those elements do not exist in the DOM:

You also should be calling `outputResult` after `currentResultOutput` and `currentCalculationOutput` have been declared.

```html
<body>

<section id="results">
  <h2 id="current-calculation">0</h2>
  <h2>Result: <span id="current-result">0</span></h2>
</section>

<script src="assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you can listen for the [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) and execute the code in the listener to ensure that your code is executed only when all elements have been loaded:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let currentResult = 1;
    currentResult = currentResult + 10;

    const currentResultOutput = document.getElementById('current-result');
    const currentCalculationOutput = document.getElementById('current-calculation');

    function outputResult(result, text) {
        currentResultOutput.textContent = result;
        currentCalculationOutput.textContent = text;
    }
    
    outputResult(currentResult, '');
    alert(currentResult);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're telling me that the webpage is not updating in the browser, this is not a programming question, but an development environment problem.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure you have to add the script tag after the elements in question so that they exist by the time the JavaScript code executes and references them.

```
<body>

<section id="results">
  <h2 id="current-calculation">0</h2>
  <h2>Result: <span id="current-result">0</span></h2>
</section>

<script src="assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: The problem lies inside the javascript

Comment: See joshuaprakasam's answer above, it wasn't the dev environment. But yes on your second point, thanks.

Comment: @SxH Ok. But you said "not everything updates. For example, if I changed the 0 to a 10 directly in the html." Assuming the JavaScript wasn't working, this part of your question was a problem with your setup and not the code. Anyway, great that you got it fixed. I didn't even notice the mistake that the accepted answer pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `currentResultOutput` and `currentCalculationOutput` before calling `outputResult`, even if the function is after you declared them in the code.

Also i suggest adding the `defer` tag to the script tags in the html like so:

```html
<script defer src="assets/scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script defer src="assets/scripts/app.js"></script>
```